# Timer and Dispatcher Timer in Emulator vs. Device

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I need to use a timer in my WP7 application and display it's value in the UI.
I managed to get it working two ways: one using the `DispatcherTimer` class and the other using the `Timer` class.

The problem is that the `DispatcherTimer` is slower than "real-time" and the `Timer` class actually goes faster than "real-time". So both go wrong.

Is this because I'm running it in the emulator? Don't have a device to test it on. Anyone had this issue and tested on both?

Comment: What level of precision do you need?

Comment: Lets say milisecond precision. But that's not the issue here. The issue is that it either goes faster or slower compared to the system clock.

Comment: For example in 10 seconds real time, the DispatcherTimer would count 7 seconds while the Timer class would count 13 seconds. Is this because of the emulator? Will it go real-time on the device? 10 seconds = 10 seconds.

Comment: I haven't had any issues with timers on the actual device. Apps like RunKeeper works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show time accurate to one second on screen, I use a `DispatcherTimer` that updates every 500 milliseconds and then subtract the current time from the start time to get the time elapsed and display that on-screen.

Does that help?

Comment: I ended up using the Timer class. Restarting the emulator fixed the bug I had. Thx for the answer anyways.